# How do I fix this System.StackOverFlow exception in my Pong code?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am trying to make Pong in XNA/C# using a class for the Paddle and Ball

Game1.cs:

```cpp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Pong
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Paddle Paddle1 = new Paddle();

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

            Paddle1.Draw();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Paddle.cs:

```cpp
namespace Pong
{
    class Paddle
    {
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        ContentManager Content;

        Texture2D paddle1;
        Texture2D paddle2;

        Vector2 Paddle1;
        Vector2 Paddle2;

        public void LoadContent()
        {
            paddle1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongpaddle1");

            Paddle1 = new Vector2();
            Paddle1.X = 50;
            Paddle1.Y = 50;
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin(); //Causes NullReferenceException was unhandled, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            spriteBatch.Draw(paddle1, Paddle1, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have anything in the Ball class yet, but it will use similar methods to Paddle.cs

Every time I've ran the code, I keep getting a System.StackOverFlow exception whenever it hits this line of code in Game1.cs:

```cpp
Paddle Paddle1 = new Paddle();
```

How do I fix this? I don't see how it's run out of memory already.

EDIT: Updated code.

Comment: You usually fix SO errors by letting your program run inside a debugger, let it break upon exceptions and then inspect the call stack carefully, then think hard about why the SO occurs and how to fix this.

Comment: Thats what I'm using is Visual C# 2010 Express, and it's giving me:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Pong.exe

Comment: Posting your code for the `Paddle1` property directly in question would help.

Comment: I suspect you are calling the setter from the setter in your property code, but I'm not going to look in paste bin to check.

Comment: Set current method = `Paddle` constructor. For Each method In current method: { If current method is Paddle constructor Then { Found possible cause } Else { Repeat for method } }

Comment: Your load content is recursively loading itself.

Comment: @ ChrisF, the code I posted is the entirety of the code.

Comment: @BillFountaine remove this line from game1.cs 

`Paddle1.LoadContent();` you are telling it to load in both the parent and child class. That is recursive calling = infinite loop = SO error

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
         Paddle Paddle1 = new Paddle();
         Paddle Paddle2 = new Paddle();
    ...
     protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Paddle1.LoadContent();
        }
    ...
    }

    class Paddle : Game1
    {
    ...
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            Paddle1 = new Vector2();
            Paddle1.X = 50;
            Paddle1.Y = 50;
            base.LoadContent();
        }
    ...
    }
```

Two big problems here, there is a recursive LoadContent call. Not to mention your paddles have paddles which have paddles... Why is your paddle inheriting from Game1? It almost **definitely shouldn't** be.

Also your paddle instances **instantiate other paddle instances**, so you're in a loop of instantiating other paddle classes.
It seems like you might want to take a step back and just get used to some basic code first? For what it's worth, I [wrote pong](http://unclearthoughts.net/tag/pong) in xna for fun a few years back, it's a bit messy, but it might give you some starting help.

Here is an example of a paddle class based off the DrawableGameComponent class (drawn in primatives so it's a bit verbose):

```
public class Paddle : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private readonly VertexPositionColor[] _vertices = new VertexPositionColor[6];
    private readonly float _width;
    private readonly float _height;

    private IndexBuffer _indexbuffer;
    private VertexBuffer _vertexbuffer;

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Direction { get; set; }
    public float Speed { get; set; }

    public Paddle(Game game, float width, float height)
        : base(game)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        base.LoadContent();

        _vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        _vertices[0].Color = Color.Red;

        _vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(_width, _height, 0);
        _vertices[1].Color = Color.Green;

        _vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(0, _height, 0);
        _vertices[2].Color = Color.Blue;

        _vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(_width, 0, 0);
        _vertices[3].Color = Color.Green;

        _vertexbuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), _vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        _vertexbuffer.SetData(_vertices);

        var indices = new short[6];
        indices[0] = 0;
        indices[1] = 1;
        indices[2] = 2;
        indices[3] = 0;
        indices[4] = 3;
        indices[5] = 1;

        _indexbuffer = new IndexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(short), 6, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        _indexbuffer.SetData(indices);
    }

    public BoundingBox GetBoundingBox()
    {
        return new BoundingBox(Position, Position + new Vector3(_width, _height, 0));
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(_vertexbuffer);
        GraphicsDevice.Indices = _indexbuffer;
        GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was inheriting from Game1 to gain access to certain Methods, like Draw. Which seemingly won't work even when placing the correct using statements.

Comment: Then override DrawableGameComponent

Comment: Bill, see my updated answer, each paddle you make, makes two more paddles, which is why it dies so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that `Paddle` inherits `Game1`. `Game1` creates `new Paddle`s:

```
Paddle Paddle1 = new Paddle();
Paddle Paddle2 = new Paddle();
```

Those `Paddle`s are `Game`s that need to initialize their own set of `Paddle`s. Infinite recursion! I'm not sure how XNA works, but if that's how the inheritance should be, just move your initializations to `Initialize()`:

```
// TODO: Add your initialization logic here

base.Initialize();
this.Paddle1 = new Paddle();
this.Paddle2 = new Paddle();
```

I kind of doubt that a game object should inherit from the game itself, though. That would seem like a rather poor design decision.

Comment: I'm still learning how to program correctly. It's a pain to learn when there are a million tutorials/books out there and none seem to help for squat :/